# Kannel PlaySMS configarations

Tags: kannel

I have already configured Kannel and can send and receive message throw web-browser, and trying to install PlaySMS and configuring PlaySMS but now cannot send or receive message from PlaySMS interface, and PS not writing any logs. In my Apache`s logs I see that:

"GET /playsms/index.php?app=menu&inc=send_sms&op=sendsmstopv&message=Hi+u+there%2C+good+morning%21%21&errid=46 HTTP/1.0" 200 2843 "$

If somebody has experiens to work with connecting Kannel+PlaySMS pls provide me some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you setup Kannel as a gateway in PlaySMS?

Setup Kannel as a gateway:

- Login as admin to PlaySMS
- Click Gateway > Manage KAnnel
- Enter your username (playsms) and the IP address of the server with Kannel installed. If Kannel is installed on the same server as PlaySMS enter "localhost"
- Enter the Send SMS port (from your kannel.conf file in the section called "smsbox" where it says "sendsms-port")
- Enter playSMS web URL (probably `http://localhost/playsms`)

Make sure you have an entry in your kannel.conf for playsms to connect, something like this should work:

```
group = sendsms-user
username = playsms
password = playsms
user-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
user-allow-ip = "<<see note below>>"
```

Please note that you should either enter the IP address of the server that PlaySMS is installed on under "user-allow-ip" OR enter "localhost" as the IP if the server is the same for both playSMS and Kannel.

Don't forget to stop and start kannel to reload the configuration file.

Comment: Kannel configuration is fine and it's working and store is MySQL but anyway messages statuses is orange should be green

Answer (score 0):

You need to get kannel to store it in the mysql db that playsms is using - look into the smsbox program to see how sms is handled
the bearerbox has a client smsbox connected to it, and that smsbox is handling the distribution of the sms and also wether or not to make reply